# How can I speed up the code that contains the sql query?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

My dataframe contains about **650 thousand** unique rows. For each row, I need to get a value from the database. I use a for loop, but the execution time is catastrophically long, about **25 hours**. How can I speed up code execution? I assume that you need to parallelize the execution using joblib or numba. But the presence of an sql query inside the loop body is confusing.

```
for x in tqdm_notebook(range(len(table))):
    good = table.iloc[x, 0]
    store = table.iloc[x, 1]
    start = table.iloc[x, 6]

    query = f"""
    SELECT 
            good_id,
            store_id,
            AVG(sale) AS avg_sale,
            SUM(sale) AS sum_sale,
            MAX(sale) AS max_sale,
            MIN(sale) AS min_sale
    FROM my_table
    WHERE good_id = {good}
    AND store_id = {store}
    AND date_id BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -2, '{start}') AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, '{start}')
    GROUP BY good_id, store_id
    """
    temp = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
    if not temp.empty:
        table.iloc[x, 13] = temp['avg_sale'].values
        table.iloc[x, 14] = temp['sum_sale'].values
        table.iloc[x, 15] = temp['max_sale'].values
        table.iloc[x, 16] = temp['min_sale'].values
```

Comment: Because you're using Python format strings instead of [read_sql() with a parameterized query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) every iteration will have a different SQL statement and take a query compilation hit. Does my_table have a covering index on good_id, store_id, date_id?

Comment: The table has a column storage, its size is about 1 billion rows.

Comment: I would abandon the idea of doing 650 thousand separate queries here anyway. If you must do that you at least should have an index on `good_id,store_id, date_id INCLUDE (Sale)`. Just relying on The columnstore will mean all rows are read every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you might just widen out your query and get all the (store,good,day) tuples, fetch partial aggregations for those, and and perform final filtering and aggregation in pandas.  Note you change `AVG` to `COUNT(*)` and calculate AVG in the final aggregate.

And a handy way to pass a list of parameters to SQL Server is with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Just send a string parameter with a JSON array of scalars like

```
'[123,324,445,23,1322]'
```

or

```
'["abd","def","d"]'
```

So something like

```
SELECT 
        good_id,
        store_id,
        date_id,
        count(*)  AS count_sale.
        SUM(sale) AS sum_sale,
        MAX(sale) AS max_sale,
        MIN(sale) AS min_sale
FROM my_table
WHERE good_id in (select cast(value as int) from openjson(?))
AND store_id in (select cast(value as int) from openjson(?))
AND date_id BETWEEN ? and ?
GROUP BY good_id, store_id, date_id
ORDER BY good_id, store_id, date_id
```